# Как сделать описание функциям внутри самого юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помню когда ставил какой-то из ассетов, где-то с год назад, там возле каждой переменной и кнопки в скрипте, при наведении всплывало окошко, поясняющее что делает эта кнопка или переменная.

Вот пример накидал, как-то так было, только само окошко было желтоватого цвета, все что помню, уж извините.

[image: вот пример]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, вы ищите [ToolTip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TooltipAttribute.html) атрибут. Пример использования из документации:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Health value between 0 and 100.")]
    int health = 0;
}
```

Comment: именно, спасибо большое вам!